# Define a key value pair type from a single keyed interface

Tags: typescript

Given an interface with a single key and value :

```
interface A {
    B : string
}
```

I'd like to be able to define a key-value type:

```
interface C {
   "key"   : B,
   "value" : string
}
```

But I don't want to have to do this manually, I'd like to be able to write a generic type/interface to do it, and do it based on a single type argument.

EG

```
interface KeyValueify<T> {
   ...
}
```

such that `C` above is equivalent to `KeyValueify<A>`

What is the magic in `...` that will make it work?

This is my attempt so far :

```
interface KeyValueify<T> {
    key : (keyof T)[0],
    value : T[(keyof T)[0]]
}
```

However it complains of not being able to use string to index T.

When I try to address this it seems to just be using the any type for the value:

```
interface kv2<T extends {[key :string] : T[(keyof T)[0]]}> {
    key :   keyof T,
    value : T[(keyof T)[0]]
}
```

Any ideas or workarounds appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[0]`

```
interface KeyValueify<T> {
    key: keyof T,
    value: T[keyof T]
}
```

Comment: nice one Tao. I was just rushing to answer my own question but you got it already :D